# Multi project with 2 different builds

Tags: playframework, sbt, akka

I have the following I need to develop:

1. playframework app
2. akka http
3. shared library

Both the play and akka app need the #3 shared library.

Is it possible to create 2 different builds in a single sbt project?

So when I run the play build it will not include akka, and when I run the akka build it won't include the play code.

I just want to avoid opening and managing 2 different projects.

Answer (score 1):

I use that multi project structure with 3 subprojects:

Root `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val myLib = (project in file("my-lib"))

lazy val playJava = (project in file("play-java"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .dependsOn(myLib)

lazy val runnableApp = (project in file("runnable-app"))
  .dependsOn(myLib)
```

Where `myLib` library, that should be shared between play application `playJava` and simple java project `runnableApp`

**1.** Play `build.sbt`:

```
name := """play-java"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

**2.** runnableApp `build.sbt`:

```
name := """runnable-app"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.example.Hello")

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit"             % "junit"           % "4.12"  % "test",
  "com.novocode"      % "junit-interface" % "0.11"  % "test"
)
```

**3.** myLib `build.sbt`:

```
name := """my-lib"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit"             % "junit"           % "4.12"  % "test",
  "com.novocode"      % "junit-interface" % "0.11"  % "test"
)
```

In sbt session, we can select project. Example:

```
$ project playJava
[info] Set current project to play-java ...
```

Now we can run task over current subproject.